# Texture painting in blender

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

In sculpting mode you can switch between relative and constant detail, which determines if the stroke is affected by the distance to the mesh.

Is there something in texture painting that gives a similar result? I use thexture paint to create bumps, tthe issue is that i sometimes have to zoom in on the mesh. The problem is that it changes the size of the strokes effect.

Comment: Hi, I remember having the same issue a while back, I think it's called world scale brush or something like that and Blender didn't have it at the time but they were working on it. I'm going to check but I think it's either coming up very soon or already available on the newest Blender version.

Comment: Well...as i have heard from other sources there is no solution so its probly not there.

Answer (score 1):

In the 3d view, Texture Paint is not going to allow you to switch from screen space to relative space like you can in sculpt mode yet - but the work around is to use an Image Editor to paint in along side your 3d view so that you can use the consistent pixel size there.

Comment: I see. What would i search for if i wanted to google or use some other ways to search it?